# perl --> regex for searching for character | in a file

Tags: regex, perl

how to match a line containing character "|" using perl? 
File:

```
1. Some header 
2. | A| B| C| D| E| F|
```

I want to match with the line containing "|" character leaving the rest.
I tried below code but it didn't work.

```
if($line =~ /|/){
}
```

Comment: Something like this with multiline flag will be enoguh, [`^.*\|.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/MScYly/1/)

Comment: You need to escape the `|` character as this is a metacharacter.

Comment: Read `perldoc perlre`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`|` is a meaningful character in regexes; it you want a litteral `|` character, you need to escape it with a backslash, so:

```
if($line =~ /\|/){
    ...
}
```